# How can I "fully qualify" a logging handler class local to the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I would like to extend my logging setup to handle some events on my own, in addition to streaming them to the console. To do so, I tried to add a new class based on `logging.StreamHandler` (I am not sure whether this is the right choice):

```
import logging
import logging.config


class ListHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        print(f"this is produced by ListHandler: {msg}")


# setup logging
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': "%(asctime)s [%(module)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # Default is stderr
        },
        'list': {
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'ListHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # root logger
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'propagate': False
        },
        'testcode': {
            'handlers': ['default', 'list'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'propagate': False
        },
    },
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "version": 1,
})
log = logging.getLogger('testcode')

log.debug("a debug message")
log.info("an info message")
```

This crashes and the Traceback mentions that it cannot import `ListHandler`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 384, in resolve
    found = self.importer(used)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ListHandler'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 563, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 721, in configure_handler
    klass = self.resolve(cname)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 397, in resolve
    raise v
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 384, in resolve
    found = self.importer(used)
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'ListHandler': No module named 'ListHandler'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yop/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/scratch_27.py", line 15, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig({
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 570, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'list'
```

Why is it trying to import a module when the class is in the same file?

The [`documentation for dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema) mentions

> `class` (mandatory). This is the fully qualified name of the handler class.

**In that case, how can I "fully qualify" `ListHandler`?**

---

EDIT: I can use a workaround but would prefer not to: create an extra module to host the `ListHandler` class (say, `mylogmodule.py`), then `import mylogmodule` and reference `ListHandler` as `mylogmodule.ListHandler`.

But I would greatly prefer keeping `ListHandler` in my main code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that it is looking for the module, hence the mention of "fully qualified name." The first part of the fully qualified name would be the module this is running from. Since in your example everything is being defined in the same script where it is being run then the module it is being called from is `__main__`.

You should change the following line to:

```
'class': '__main__.ListHandler'
```

We can also observe this behavior by adding an additional logging statement on the bottom to illustrate this point.

```
log.debug(f"The fully qualified name is {ListHandler.__module__}.{ListHandler.__qualname__}")
```

Which prints:

```
2020-07-23 07:33:34,329 [test] DEBUG The fully qualified name is __main__.ListHandler
```

Comment: Thank you - I was fixed on `__name__`.

Comment: Since you defined your class in the top-level script it takes the name of `__main__`. You are correct though, the `__name__` variable is `__main__` however the logging config does not have a way of obtaining that.